# Linearly Independent in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

- *Recall*. Spans of two linearly independent vectors give us plane.

I don't see the definition as geometrically. Can you explain, can you draw?

Comment: In a plane you can get from any point to any other point by moving in no more than 2 directions.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi I wrote a comment your answer ''THE LINK DOESN'T WORK''.

Comment: @Kahler It was only an image, the original link is here https://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap1/Chap1-4/part4.htm

Comment: @gimusi Thanks.

Comment: @Kahler You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a picture which can help you:

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work